# How to add a Maven Release Plugin "pre step" to a Jenkins project

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to add support for the **"Maven Release Plugin"** to an existing Maven project that has been defined inside of our **Jenkins server**.  We have some Maven projects on the server that already use the release plugin, but I am unable to duplicate their configuration onto the Maven projects that don't already have access to the Maven Release Plugin.

I notice that in the non-plugin projects, I don't appear to have the ability to add a "**pre step**" to the project.  The projects that can perform a Maven Release have such pre steps defined, and those pre steps seem directly related to the release plugin.

So my question is two-fold: **how do I add a pre-step to a project configuration?**  If the pre-steps are only available when an appropriate plugin is associated with a project, **how do I associate the Maven Release Plugin with a project?**

Right now I could clone a project with the release plugin and then alter it to replace the project I wanted to add the release plugin to, but that seems somewhat ignorant.

I have been unable to find references to these pre-steps in my Google searches.  *Any help would be appreciated*.

Comment: Did you get an answer to what you were looking for?

Comment: @Vivin I don't recall.  That question was posted 7 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

The options depend on the job type chosen when creating a new one. Only the Maven Project includes the Maven Release options.